# How to create an image in this case?

Tags: linux, docker

I want to create an image for the gem5 environment. I saw some images about gem5 on the docker hub. But I tried a few but none of them met my requirements.
I saw a dockerfile for creating gem5 publicly. I want to imitate it. https://github.com/ericvh/docker-gem5/blob/master/Dockerfile

1. What I am confused about is why these gem5 images have downloaded and compiled gem5, and when I use gem5, I often change the files inside. In this case, should I mount the local gem5 to the container? Instead of `git clone gem5` and compile it in the dockerfile?
2. There are many paths to gem5 in the script file I wrote. Should I first create an empty gem5 directory in the same location, and then mount the local gem5? That is, modify the WORKDIR in the Dockerfile to be consistent with my local gem5 path?
3. Why do those images have to download a copy of gem5?

Comment: If your requirement is to have a container with gem5 installed, you can use any base image and then install the gem5 on it . As for they changes in files , you can have those specific files im the build context and then use a COPY inside of the docker file to replace those files after the installation is completed.

Comment: After I build the container, I will frequently modify the source code in gem5.

Comment: Or have your own git repo with your changes and clone that instead of the public one